# Is it possible to reference previous parameter as parameter default value in a C# method?

Tags: c#, methods, parameter-passing, extension-methods

I'm planning to write a C# extension method to only join a specific range of elements of a string array. For example, if I have this array:

```
+-----+  +-----+  +-------+  +------+  +------+  +-----+
| one |  | two |  | three |  | four |  | five |  | six |
+-----+  +-----+  +-------+  +------+  +------+  +-----+
   0        1         2          3         4        5
```

And I only want to join them using <kbd>,</kbd> from index 2 to index 4. I got `three,four,five`.
If the user doesn't provide start index and end index, then my `Join` method will join all array elements. Below is my method signature.

```
public static class StringSplitterJoinner
{
    public static string Join(this string[] me, string separator, int start_index = 0, int end_index = me.Length - 1) {

    }
}
```

The problem is that the parameter `end_index` can't reference the first parameter `me` and it generates an error. I don't want the user to always provide `start_index` and `end_index` I want my method has some meaningful default values. In this case, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What you want/should do are [method overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/member-overloading). Just create another method `Join` there that is not having startIndex and endIndex arguments. (If you look around in the documentation of .NET's class library, you'll see method overloads are used almost everywhere...)

Comment: How about to define last parameter as `int? end_index = null`? If user dosn't set it to something you can manually assign it in method: `end_index = end_index ?? me.Length - 1;`

Comment: Defaults have limited uses. This definitely isn't one of them. Remember that every call involving a default must be passed a value anyway, it's just that it will be inserted for you at the call site by the compiler. That alone makes them unattractive even for many scenarios where they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
public static class StringSplitterJoinner
{
    public static string Join(this string[] me, string separator, int start_index = 0, int? end_index = null)
    {
        if (!end_index.HasValue) end_index = me.Length - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: A shorter implementation of your idea `end_index = end_index ?? me.Length - 1;`

Comment: I don't like overloading when you can use default values.

Comment: Even shorter: `end_index ?= me.Length  - 1`

Comment: Even better would be `end_index ??= me.Length -1;`
Unfortunately that operator doesn't exist .

Comment: @WolfgangKleinschmit mine was a typo, `??=` is an operator (c# 8)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using *overloading*:

```
public static string Join(this string[] me, string separator) {
  //TODO: add parameters' validation

  return Join(me, separator, 0, me.Length - 1);
}

public static string Join(this string[] me, string separator, int start_index) {
  //TODO: add parameters' validation

  return Join(me, separator, start_index, me.Length - 1);
}

public static string Join(this string[] me, string separator, int start_index, int end_Index) {
  //TODO: implement logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
public static string Join<T>(this IReadOnlyCollection<T> me,
  string separator, int startIndex = 0, int endIndexInclusive = -1)
{
  if (endIndexInclusive < 0)
    endIndexInclusive += me.Count;

  var range = me.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndexInclusive - startIndex + 1);
  return string.Join(separator, range);
}
```

The idea here is that *negative* indices count from the other end, so `-1` is the last index, `-2` is the second to last index, and so on. The value taken if the argument is not specified explicitly, `-1`, means the last entry in the collection.

(You could include `if (startIndex < 0) startIndex += me.Count;` as well if you wanted.)

Method has been made general (generic) but can still be used on a `string[]`. Example:

```
string[] myArray = ...
var joined = myArray.Join(",", 2, -3); // skips first two, and last two, entries
```

Be aware that the `-3` can also be written as `~2` using bit-wise complement. That looks more symmetrical, `myArray.Join(",", 2, ~2)`.